# Load balancing using apache and weblogic plugin

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, weblogic

I am building a weblogic 12 Release 2 cluster environment with apache 2.2.10 as a load balancer , and as a required step the mod_wl_22.so should be copied to apache modules folder but i searched for this plugin and found mod_wl_22.so so I used mod_wl_24.so but after that I am not able to start tomcat and got an error

`Failed to load mod_wl_24.so to the server: % is not win32`

Comment: So you have followed the directions here: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/webtier/PLGWL/overview.htm#BABBDIBC ? Sounds like you just need to download a different version of the plugin

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp first I was looking for mod_wl_22.so but since I did not find this plugin I used mod_wl_24.so which seems not applickable with apache 2.2.10. !                                 Do you have any idea?

Comment: Follow the instructions here: http://idmoim.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-and-configuring-apache-web.html the download for the plugin is here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webtier/downloads/index.html

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp but seems that Release 2 plugins are 64 bit and the apache for windowss only 32 bit !

Comment: did you resolve? i'm in the your same trouble..

Comment: i made the same error, while my server weblogic was 64bit, i downloaded tomcat in 32bit..